# WPF How to assign the same event lambda expression to two different elements

Tags: wpf, events, lambda

I have two datagrids with same properties defined in code behind.

```
var dtg = new DataGrid();
```

then I assign an event though lambda expression (quite a long one):

```
dtg.LoadingRow += (object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) =>
{
    ...
};
```

which I do not want to replicate.
So how can I do that (pseudocode):

```
var dtg2 = new DataGrid();
dtg2.LoadingRow = dtg.LoadingRow;
```

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply assign your lambda to variable:

```
EventHandler<DataGridRowEventArgs> handler =  (object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) =>
{
    ...
};
var dtg2 = new DataGrid();
dtg2.LoadingRow += handler;
```

Or, better, name your handler - make it to an ordinary method in your class and use its name.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just replace the lambda expression with an event handler, i.e. a method?:

```
private void OnLoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    //....
}
```

You could then use the same event handler for several DataGrid's:

```
dtg.LoadingRow += OnLoadingRow;
dtg2.LoadingRow += OnLoadingRow;
```

The other option is to define your entire lamda as a variable or field as suggested by @Rafal but I can't really see why this would be better than adding a method - at least in the general case.

Comment: Since when is a lamda more compact than a method that contains the exact same logic?