# How to subscribe to two different events using the same event handler created with a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, combobox, event-handling

In reference to my older question
[WPF How to assign the same event lambda expression to two different elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717487/wpf-how-to-assign-the-same-event-lambda-expression-to-two-different-elements)

I have a slightly different need now.
I have to subscribe to different types of events using the same lambda action:

```
EventHandler action = (sender2,args) =>
{
    var cmbChanged = sender2 as ComboBox;
    //...check...
};


cmb.DropDownClosed += action;
cmb.PreviewKeyUp += action; // <----- compiler error here
```

but the compiler rightly says that an action is `System.EventHandler` while here I need `System.Window.Input.KeyEventHandler`.

In short, I have to check for some condition both when you click with the mouse and close the combo and when you choose a value by typing.

Comment: You could just move code that is inside the lambda expression to a separate method and call that method inside each event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the delegate types are different, you cannot <strike>assign</strike> add it directly. But you can forward it simply with:

```
cmb.DropDownClosed += action;
cmb.PreviewKeyUp += (sender, e) => action(sender, e);
```

Since `e` is of type `KeyEventArgs` which is derived from `EventArgs` you can pass it to `action`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Quick, clean, easy and working wonder!!

Comment: "Assign" is technically not 100% correct here, we're talking about event subscription. While this is an "addition assignment" operator per se, its meaning for events is slightly different compared to a simple assignment.